# Dealing with untracked changes in git

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I just went into a project (Wordpress theme) to pull some changes that I had committed. But it won't pull as someone has been making direct edits to the files and not using git.

What is the best way to deal with this? If I do a hard reset then the untracked changes will be lost. I could pull all the theme files down, put them in git and then re-apply my changes and pull it down again but it seems a long winded way of doing it. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Commit the changes first, then pull the new changes? It sounds like you have a non-technical problem to solve if someone is directly editing files.

Comment: Stash uncommitted files, pull, unstash.

Comment: @phd That works well if the changes are isolated; if there's any conflicts, things will get painful, because you don't have a good place to roll back to. I think committing the changes, then *merging somewhere else*, and pulling the merged copy to the live server is the safest. But I also agree with larsks that there's a non-technical issue if one person is using git to manage the files, and the other is using some other process to edit them.